# Installing temporal_tables and cyanaudit extensions in PostgreSQL for Windows

Tags: postgresql, audit-logging, temporal-tables, bi-temporal

I have an auditing and slowly changing dimensions (SCD) use case that requires the installation of the PostgreSQL **temporal_tables** and **cyanaudit** extensions.

However my PostgreSQL server is on Windows and after searching high and low, I still haven't found a way to install these extensions in PostgreSQL for Windows.

Has anyone succeeded in installing these extensions in the Windows environment and can you please share your methodology?

Thanks a million,

JDaniel

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to install these extensions on Windows but I suggest you have a look on the related source code repositories.

temporal_tables is stored on GitHub: if you search in open and closed issues about Windows installation, I have found: https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables/issues/19.

cyanaudit is stored on bitbucket and I have not found anything related to Windows.
However installation should be easier because it is mainly SQL and PL/PGSQL code: you need to be able to use tar and perl because the installer is using Perl.

Comment: The GitHub link refers to the BigSQL PostgreSQL package which does not exist anymore. I believe it was bought out or absorbed by another, larger company so I can't use that option.

Comment: I think the best you can do it to open  a new  issue on GitHub asking how to install now this extension on Windows (give your PostgreSQL version and your Windows version).

Comment: Done. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I just found this article today. It may be the solution to my question https://www.highgo.ca/2020/05/15/build-postgresql-and-extension-on-windows/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=build-postgresql-and-extension-on-windows